# Getting error while checking if a url is alive or not

Tags: java, url, http-status-codes

I want to constantly monitor whether a site is active or not using the following code in Java:

```
URL url1 = new URL ("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection code = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
System.out.println(code.getResponseCode());
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:158)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:240)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:397)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnection.java:463)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy? It may require your proxy settings to work correctly..

Comment: Yes I am behind a proxy.. Thanks codemwnci for pointing that out.. I will modify accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not able to resolve google.com . Check for your DNS settings (resolv.conf and similar files).

Comment: You're welcome. Just to verify if this is actually the problem, try by opening a console or SSH connection to your server. Try to ping google.com and see if it answers. If it doesn't, ask your sysadmin to configure your DNS, or do it yourself, or just add the IP to your hosts file (/etc/hosts in Linux/Solaris/OSX)